# List all developers on a project in Git

Tags: git

Is it possible to list all users that contributed to a project (users that have done commits) in Git?

Any additional statistics?

Answer (score 670, accepted):

To show all users & emails, and the number of commits in the CURRENT branch:

```
git shortlog --summary --numbered --email
```

Or simply:

```
git shortlog -sne
```

To show users from **all branches** (not only the ones in the current branch) you have to add `--all` flag:

```
git shortlog -sne --all
```

Comment: Note that if you want to use this command from within a script, or something like "ant", you must specify a revision or it outputs nothing.  For the current revision you can use HEAD: `git shortlog -sn HEAD`

Comment: To get e-mail addresses as well, add `-e`.

Comment: To show users from all branches (not only the ones in the current branch) you have to add `--all` flag

Comment: what if I dont want the number of commits?

Comment: This is also great for checking who touched a specific file rather than the whole project. `git shortlog --summary --numbered <pathToFile>`

Comment: Is it possible to list the users that have access currently?

Comment: @Nevin no because this does not have any correlation with github access. This is just parsing git history. You should be able to do so through their web API, but it's out of scope here.

Answer (score 63):

If you want to be more specific in the list (find a list of unique committer and author), you could use `git log`:

```
git log --pretty="%an %ae%n%cn %ce" | sort -u
```

- `%an` author name
- `%ae` author email
- `%n` new line
- `%cn` committer name
- `%ce` committer email

Other placeholders are described in the [pretty print documentation of `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/#_pretty_formats).

Comment: I think the `%n` does not make too much sense in combination with (line-based) `sort`, does it ? The line logs author / committer name / email in separate lines, but sorts over the entire output...

Comment: @ssc committer email can be different from author email. %n is for new line to find those differences

Comment: Use `git log --pretty="%aN <%aE>%n%cN <%cE>" | sort | uniq    ` to respect a `.mailmap` file

Comment: adding the extra `uniq` parameter `-c` and sorting again you can get also the count per author displayed.  ex: `| sort | uniq -c | sort`

Answer (score 30):

You can try this:

```
git log | grep Author: | sort -u
```

Comment: This is the most useful command for anyone interested in updating their .mailmap file!

Comment: especially with the `--use-mailmap` arg

Answer (score 11):

> (users that have done commits)

Note: by default [`git shortlog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) groups commits by *authors*.

If you need to group them by committers, you will need Git 2.12 (Q1 2017)

```
git shortlog -snc
```

See [commit 03f4082](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03f40829ad22deb7b6950cfc28a3779ece9e6a56) (16 Dec 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit fbfda15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbfda15fb8daf7388a19b8bed2f319a8c1b6c5f1) (11 Oct 2016) by [Linus Torvalds (`torvalds`)](https://github.com/torvalds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ad1b4e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad1b4e2c0e5521da39e13088f197b256303a2fc8), 27 Dec 2016)</sup>

Linus Torvalds himself introduces this feature:

> ### `shortlog`: group by committer information
>
> In some situations you may want to group the commits not by author,
>   but by committer instead.
>
> For example, when I just wanted to look up what I'm still missing from `linux-next` in the current merge window, I don't care so much about who
>   wrote a patch, as what `git tree` it came from, which generally boils
>   down to "who committed it".
>
> So make git shortlog take a "`-c`" or "`--committer`" option to switch grouping to that.

Answer (score 5):

Great answers by @pedro-nascimento, by @mic_e and others already solve the problem.

In addition, you can add the following line to your `.gitconfig`

```
contributors = shortlog -e --summary --numbered
```

or in shell type

```
git config --global alias.contributors 'shortlog -e --summary --numbered'
```

And after that you can simply invoke: `git contributors`

Comment: you should probably add a note that after setting this you can simply call `git contributors`

Answer (score 3):

Another option can be:

```
git log --format='%aN' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using the [`mergestat` CLI](https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat), which is a tool that allows you to run SQL queries on git history. So a query like:

```
SELECT
  author_name,
  author_email count(*),
  count(*)
FROM commits
GROUP BY author_name, author_email
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Will output a list of all commit authors in a repo, ordered by number of commits. Since it's just SQL, you can add filtering for commit timestamps, or sort by LOC added/removed, etc.

Full disclosure, I'm the maintainer/creator of the project, but wanted to share because I believe it could be useful for this type of use case.

There's also the [`summary`](https://docs.mergestat.com/getting-started-cli/summary) command which prints out git stats by author in a repo.

Comment: Looks awesome. Cool and easy way to interact with git. Kind of interesting that [mergestat lite](https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat-lite) is 10x more stars than mergestat haha.

Answer (score 2):

I am using GHI to open issues and where I can assign issues to specific users as long as I know their usernames

I don't if this is going to be helpful for someone but I am just going to leave the solution that worked for me here:

To get only the authors username from the GitHub I ran

```
git shortlog -sne | grep +  | sed -e "s/.*+//; s/@.*//"
```

which will only list the username of the authors on the current project.

Then i can pick an username and assign an issue to him/her.

FOR ANYONE WHO WANTS TO OPEN ISSUES AND/OR ASSIGN TO SOMEONE FROM CMD/TERMINAL, HERE THE DOCUMENTATION OF THE ***GHI***
https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`git-extras`](https://vimeo.com/45506445) installed you can use one of its helpful (and easy to remember) commands, such as `git authors` or `git count`.

A list of authors, including email addresses, ordered by commit count:

```
git authors --list
```

A list of authors and the number of their contributions i.e. commits:

```
git count --all
```

---

The commands are shell scripts that use Git commands themselves. You can inspect the [source code](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) on GitHub, e.g.

[git-authors](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/main/bin/git-authors) is implemented as:

```
git shortlog HEAD -sne | awk '{$1=""; sub(" ", ""); print}' | awk -F'<' '!x[$1]++' | awk -F'<' '!x[$2]++'
```

[git-count](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/main/bin/git-count) is implemented as:

```
git shortlog -n -s | awk '{print substr($0,index($0,$2)) " (" $1 ")"}'
```

Comment: git shortlog -ns seems less hackish

Comment: @TomDLT since I posted this 4 years ago, this example script in git-extras has changed. But I think my advice to look at git scripts from projects like git-extras or from peoples' dotfiles is still great advice. If you are looking for interesting git commands then I would recommend Gary Bernhardt's dotfiles as well: https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/tree/master/bin

Answer (score 0):

List authors (from all branches) and their emails by last commit date for checking which authors are still active in the project:

```
git log --all --pretty="%ae,%an,%ad" | sort -u -t, -k1,1
```