# How can I find & list the names of all developers on an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

Is there an easy way to go through an Xcode project that has been worked on by many people and find all of the different "created by XXXXX" names from the .h and .m files?

Comment: Whats wrong with the find navigator?

Comment: Does this project use Git? If YES: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597410/list-all-developers-on-project-in-git Because "Created By", do not take in account developers that may have changed lines but not created a file.

Comment: The find navigator gives hundreds of results - Is there a way to export the find results so I can process the results down to unique developers?

Comment: Yes, project uses Git and I have used git shortlog -sn to identify developer git ID's and emails.  However, I don't think this would include developers who created files that were later added to the project by other developers.