# How to get all the user commits from a Bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a task like, to get all the user commits from Bitbucket.

Can someone assist to get the all list of users mailId or name using git command?
From that list I can get full commit details of each.

Answer (score 11):

If you can clone that repository from BitBucket to your workstation, you can then [list all the user emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597462/6309):

```
git shortlog --summary --numbered --email
```

For each one, you can then [list all their commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260053/6309).

```
git log --author="username"
```

Answer (score -1):

$ git clone git@gitlab.xxx.com:applicaiton/app.git #clone from Bitbucket repository

$ cd app # app is your local code dir

$ git log -3 #list the latest 3 commit logs, and use grep commond to filter