# How to list all users having current access on a project in Git

Tags: git

How to list all users that have current access to a project in Git? I looked into following

[List all developers on a project in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597410/list-all-developers-on-a-project-in-git)

which lists all users that have contributed to the project. Is there a way to list all users that can access it currently?

Comment: Git itself has no access control. Zero, nada, zilch, nothing. Therefore, by definition, *something else* provides the access control. It depends on the "something else". GitHub? See GitHub. Bitbucket? See Bitbucket. GitLab? Well, if it's GitLab on *your* system, see ... yourself. :-)

Comment: @torek I can see a user.passwd which contains user names and encrypted passwords, can it be the access control?

Comment: There is no `user.passwd` in [`.git/config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Answer (score 0):

> I can see a `user.passwd` which contains user names and encrypted passwords

You would have to be more explicit as to *where* you see that file, in which environment, OS version, etc.
But Git itself has no notion of users or `user.passwd`.

You can list [all current contributors in a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325643/6309), but this has nothing to do as "having access" (which involves **authorization**, [something that Git does not manage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5685757/6309))

Comment: Its in /opt/git directory in Ubuntu, i think its apache who is managing it